# Webpack file-loader emits png with different name than the one referenced in emitted bundle.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

I'm trying to find my way around Webpack file loader with a simple practice project.
I've put an `icon.png`in `./src`, along with `index.js` and `style.css` (as per https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/).
After running webpack (via `yarn build or watch scripts`) I get no errors, and actually get a file called `a0cadc7b7cbb7dd92495c1d9567c52e7.png`in `./dist`.
However, the file referenced by the resulting bundle is different when checked in the dev-tools (`dista0cadc7b7cbb7dd92495c1d9567c52e7.png`) and thus it's not loaded at all.

This is really puzzling... Any ideas to solve this issue?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader'
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

**index.js**

```
import sayHello from './hello';
import './style.css';
import icon from './icon.png';
sayHello();

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement("div");
  element.innerHTML = "Hello from webpack!";
  element.classList.add("hello");


  const myIcon = new Image();
  myIcon.src = icon;
  element.appendChild(myIcon);
  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

**style.css**

```
.hello {
  color: red;
  background-image: url('./icon.png');
}
```

Also: **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress -p",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "server-c9": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --progress"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.4.0",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

***Update:***
I commented out `publicPath` in `webpack.config.js` and got it to work... but without that I lost Live Reloading in webpack-dev-server... Which is now my first subject for this unexpected behavior...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are using **publicPath** in webpack config wrongly. You could just remove it for now or replace to default value "./"

Please read [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#environment-based) for more details

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. According to https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images, I removed

```
use: [
      'file-loader'
    ],
```

from `webpack.config.js`. Instead, added

```
type: 'asset/resource',
```

and it worked for me. However, if I use `file-loader`, image will not show up.